# BOSCH SMU69T42SK Door not closing

Tags: dishwasher

I recently got a BOSCH SMU69T42SK dishwasher for free. The door wont close, the person i got it from said that one of her kids sat on the left side of the door when it was open. The door doenst feel loose and its not moving up and down by the hinge if you pull or push it. The door doesnt look crooked either. Any ideas to what is wrong and how i can fix it? Im willing to use some time and money to fix it since its only 2 years old and i got it for free.

Comment: Don’t have experience w/ this specific model, but look down around the hinge for a linkage (string/wire) that leads to a spring. You might find something broken there.

Comment: And the last time I had something like this with a Bosch, the pivot points were integral to the tub, so prepare your mcgyver skills.

Comment: `won't close` is a vague description of a problem ... please update your question with a clear description of the problem ... add pictures if necessary

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.